# Compilation Encoder error on spark 2.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to move from spark 1.6 to 2.0, I get this error during compilation on 2.0 only:

```
def getSubGroupCount(df: DataFrame, colNames: String): Array[Seq[Any]] = {
   val columns: Array[String] = colNames.split(',')
   val subGroupCount: Array[Seq[Any]] = columns.map(c => df.select(c).distinct.map(x => x.get(0)).collect.toSeq)
    subGroupCount
  }
```

> Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
>   val subGroupCount: Array[Seq[Any]] = columns.map(c => df.select(c).distinct.map(x => x.get(0)).collect.toSeq)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The method `DataFrame.map` has changed between the versions:

- In Spark 1.6, it operates on the underlying `RDD[Row]` and returns an `RDD`:

  ```
  def map[R](f: (Row) ⇒ R)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[R]): RDD[R]
  ```
- In Spark 2.0, `DataFrame` is just an alias for `Dataset[Row]`, and therefore it returns a `Dataset`:

  ```
  def map[U](func: (T) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
  ```

As you can see, the latter expects an implicit `Encoder` argument, which is missing in your case.

**Why is the Encoder missing**?

First, all default encoders will be in scope once you import `spark.implicits._`. However, since the mapping's result type is `Any` (`x => x.get(0)` returns `Any`), you won't have an Encoder for it.

**How to fix this?**

1. If there's a common type (say, `String`, for the sake of example) for all the columns you're interested in, you can use `getAs[String](0)` to make the mapping function's return type specific. Once the above mentioned import is added, such types (primitives, Products) will have a matching Encoder in scope
2. If you don't have a known type that is common for all the relevant columns, and want to retain the same behavior - you can get the Dataframe's `RDD` using `.rdd` and use that RDD's `map` operation, which will be identical to the pre-2.0 behavior:

   ```
   columns.map(c => df.select(c).distinct.rdd.map(x => x.get(0)).collect.toSeq)
   ```